# Can we handle ConsumerRebalanceException in Kafka in our client java code?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We have developed a application in JAVA which is using Kafka/Zookeeper as pub-sub model. We are getting the below exception:

error during syncedRebalance: kafka.common.ConsumerRebalanceFailedException

Due to this reason the Consumer are getting detached from the partitions and becoming dead. Can we catch the above exception , so that our consumer doesn't dies out. It should catch the exception and proceeds.

Comment: Can someone please guide?

Comment: You can for sure catch the exception. Not sure, if you can reuse the existing Consumer object or if you need to instantiate a new one -- for sure, your JVM must not die and you can recover from this exception.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Can you please comment how the exception can be propagated? I have gone thru kafka codebase and have found that the watcher thread does a syncRebalance and the exception is propagated from syncRebalance ? My application code no way  call the syncRebalance.